# How can I define the 100-period exponential moving average (EMA) equal to its previous value in pine script V5?

Tags: pine-script

How can I define the 100-period exponential moving average (EMA) equal to its previous value in pine script?

I tried this

```
C8 = nz(ema100[1],ema100)
```

but nothing happened. I want to eliminate some entry errors from an indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change your syntax a little, but you have the right idea. The 'equal' variable checks if the previous value is equal to the current value

```
ma = ta.ema(close, 100)
equal = ma[1] == ma
```

Comment: I tried it but still is not working. many thanks.